# how to publish newly created component on front end in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, frontend, joomla-component

i had created a new component for first time. its back end functions are all working well. now i want to show that in front end. i created a new menu item and selects this new component but on front end when i clicked on my menu Error 500 with `View not found [name, type, prefix]: tenders, html, tendersView`.
my site folder structure is:

```
joomla
  |components
     |com_tenders
        |controller.php
        |tenders.php
        |models
            |tenders.php
        |views
           |tenders
               |view.html.php
               |tmpl
                   |default.php
```

**com_tenders/controller.php**

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access'); 

jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

class TendersController extends JController {

      public function display() {

        $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        $input->set('view', $input->getCmd('view', 'Tenders'));
        parent::display();
      }
}
?>
```

**views/tenders/view.html.php**

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access'); 

jimport('joomla.application.component.view');

class TendersViewTenders extends JView {

    function display($tpl = null) {

    $model =& $this->getModel();
    $msg = $model->getMsg();
    $this->assignRef('msg',$msg );

    parent::display($tpl);

    }
}
?>
```

**models/tenders.php**

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
jimport('joomla.application.component.modelitem');

class TendersModelTenders extends JModelItem {

     public function getMsg() {
           $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
           $query = "SELECT * FROM #__tenders";
           $db->setQuery( $query );
           $msg = $db->loadResult();

           return $msg;
     }
}
?>
```

please let me know if need any clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

In **views/tenders/view.html.php** rename class from `TendersViewTender` to `TendersViewTenders`

You need to have **tenders.php** file too in your **com_tenders** folder. Which should look something like this:

```
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
require_once (JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'controller.php');

$controller = new TendersController( );

$controller->execute( JRequest::getCmd('task'));
$controller->redirect();
```

Comment: rename your model too. To TendersModelTenders

Comment: I've updated answer, please check and let me know if it helps.

Comment: thank u for ur response sir... i have that file already.even though i updated my tenders.php file with your codes. but again the same error "View not found [name, type, prefix]: tenders, html, tendersView" occurs.